# Profits of US Banks

Tags: data, market-data, banks

Are there any publicly available data on [aggregate] profits for domestic US banks, especially quarterly data? Most studies that I know use the "Financial Statements of Banks" from the OECD but these are only annual data.

Apart from [this] the Board of Governors of the FED is releasing the "The Financial Accounts of the United States" (source: https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/Z1/current/default.htm). For the data download program see: https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Choose.aspx?rel=Z1

Unfortunately I can't really find any useful data on profits for domestic banks. FRED has only data on Net-interest income or Income for domestic banks but this data are not very helpful

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by aggregate profits? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm talking about "net income" or "profits" for all commercial Banks in the US. 

Does anybody knows where I can find earlier data on the call reports from the FFIEC? I only have the following link: https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx where I can access the data from 2000 to 2017. But I'm sure that most of the data goes back to 1984.

Comment: What classifies a bank as commercial? And you are aware that it is extremely difficult to get data on non-public companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `getFundamentals(ticker)` provided by the package `eodhistoricaldata-api` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eodhistoricaldata-api).

The library returns quarterly, and yearly profits (included in the income statement), and other fundamentals, such as balance sheets, and cash flow statements. The data is provided in **JSON** - no need to parse XBRL. You need to know the ticker symbol of the banks you are looking for.

For example:

```
"Highlights": {
    "MarketCapitalization": 54915055616,
    "MarketCapitalizationMln": "54915.0556",
    "EBITDA": 616286976,
    "PERatio": null,
    "PEGRatio": "-1.5700",
    "WallStreetTargetPrice": "321.8900",
    "BookValue": "26.2790",
    "DividendShare": null,
    "DividendYield": null,
    "EarningsShare": "-4.8500",
    "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": "-6.5600",
    "EPSEstimateNextYear": "-2.0000",
    "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": "-1.6700",
    "MostRecentQuarter": "2018-09-30",
    "ProfitMargin": "-0.1022",
    "OperatingMarginTTM": "-0.0710",
    "ReturnOnAssetsTTM": "-0.0271",
    "ReturnOnEquityTTM": "-0.3397",
    "RevenueTTM": "17523644416.00",
    "RevenuePerShareTTM": "103.3240",
    "QuarterlyRevenueGrowthYOY": "1.2860",
    "GrossProfitTTM": "2222487000.00",
    "DilutedEpsTTM": "-10.5600",
    "QuarterlyEarningsGrowthYOY": null
},
// ...
"Income_Statement": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "researchDevelopment": "350848000.00",
                "effectOfAccountingCharges": null,
                "incomeBeforeTax": "271320000.00",
                "minorityInterest": "1344731000.00",
                "netIncome": "311516000.00",
                "sellingGeneralAdministrative": "729876000.00",
                "grossProfit": "1523665000.00",
                "ebit": "442941000.00",
                "operatingIncome": "442941000.00",
                "otherOperatingExpenses": null,
                "interestExpense": "-169858000.00",
                "extraordinaryItems": null,
                "nonRecurring": null,
                "otherItems": null,
                "incomeTaxExpense": "16647000.00",
                "totalRevenue": "6824413000.00",
                "totalOperatingExpenses": "6381472000.00",
                "costOfRevenue": "5300748000.00",
                "totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet": "-171621000.00",
                "discontinuedOperations": null,
                "netIncomeFromContinuingOps": "254673000.00",
                "netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares": "311516000.00"
            },
            // ...
"Balance_Sheet": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "intangibleAssets": "291476000.00",
                "totalLiab": "23409144000.00",
                "totalStockholderEquity": "4508838000.00",
                "deferredLongTermLiab": "0.00",
                "otherCurrentLiab": "2266778000.00",
                "totalAssets": "29262713000.00",
                "commonStock": "171000.00",
                "otherCurrentAssets": "158627000.00",
                "retainedEarnings": "-5457315000.00",
                "otherLiab": "2285172000.00",
                "goodWill": "65226000.00",
                "otherAssets": "1233979000.00",
                "cash": "2967504000.00",
                "totalCurrentLiabilities": "9775324000.00",
                "shortLongTermDebt": "2106538000.00",
                "otherStockholderEquity": "8271000.00",
                "propertyPlantEquipment": "19733969000.00",
                "totalCurrentAssets": "7920491000.00",
                "longTermInvestments": "17572000.00",
                "netTangibleAssets": "4152136000.00",
                "shortTermInvestments": "0.00",
                "netReceivables": "1155001000.00",
                "longTermDebt": "9726589000.00",
                "inventory": "3314127000.00",
                "accountsPayable": "3596984000.00",
                "totalPermanentEquity": "0.00",
                "noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity": "0.00",
                "temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests": "0.00",
                "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome": "0.00",
                "additionalPaidInCapital": "0.00",
                "commonStockTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "preferredStockTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "retainedEarningsTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "treasuryStock": "0.00"
            },
            // ...
"Cash_Flow": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "investments": null,
                "changeToLiabilities": "895197000.00",
                "totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities": "-560965000.00",
                "netBorrowings": "-221931000.00",
                "totalCashFromFinancingActivities": "-84218000.00",
                "changeToOperatingActivities": "98770000.00",
                "netIncome": "311516000.00",
                "changeInCash": "739728000.00",
                "totalCashFromOperatingActivities": "1391281000.00",
                "depreciation": "502825000.00",
                "otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities": "128600000.00",
                "dividendsPaid": "0.00",
                "changeToInventory": "-55055000.00",
                "changeToAccountReceivables": "-587594000.00",
                "salePurchaseOfStock": "0.00",
                "otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities": "42839000.00",
                "changeToNetincome": "179168000.00",
                "capitalExpenditures": "-559765000.00"
            },
```

The package supports client-side (React, React Native, Angular, Vue, etc.), and server-side (Node.js, etc.) JavaScript.

The documentation on the package's website goes into greater details.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check what [FDIC](https://www.fdic.gov/bank/statistical/guide/data.html) has. They have a lot of quarterly data for bank balance sheets. Unfortunately, I don't think they have data for all US banks, only the ones they insure.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how many percent of US banks are part of the FDIC?

Comment: I don't know the percentage, but I know that all banks that accept deposits are FDIC insured. You can read more about US banks [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banking_in_the_United_States).

Comment: There are 5779 FDIC insured banks in the US, with 13 trillion in deposits. It represesnts most of the banks and the deposits.

Answer (score 1):

such data is provided by the SEC through their Edgar search tool, which you can find here: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm

Though they provide the Information as XBRL data or in form of the regular statements like those you find on the IR pages of the respective companies.

Our startup SimFin, provides the kind of data you are searching for and it is for free, since we couldn't afford the pricey premium solutions back when we were students and wanted to overcome the hegemony of the data market.

To this date, we have financial ratios, Financial statements (directly sourced from the SEC's XBRL data and up to 10y back) and stock prices for over 1000+ US equities, including big indices like the S&P 500. you can browse and compile all periods (quarterly, half-year or 9M) from fundamental financial data according to your needs and then instantly download it as excel.

Also, as far as the financial statements go, we display both the original as well as the standardized statements and make it transparent how we transition from one to the other.

Feel free to check it out under https://simfin.com
and hopefully find what you are looking for.

Hope i could help!